# Not getting to Web Inspector in Safari 9

Tags: safari, web-inspector

[OS X 10.11, Safari 9.1]

When I enable the developer tools and select **Show Web Inspector** from the **Develop** menu I don't see anything at all like the Web Inspectors shown in Apple documentation and various web pages I found by search. 
Can someone explain my problem and how to solve it?

Here's what I get by opening the Web Inspector on the page I am at when writing this request.

[image] Apple's documentation shows the following: (My guess is that the dramatic coloring is just for the documentation and doesn't appear in the actual tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot you have from the documentation is simply taken from an older version of Safari. And yes, the coloring is just for illustrative purposes in the documentation.

On your own screenshot, you can click the "+" button to the next of the Elements tab to gain access to the extra stuff you see in the documentation - for example Debugger, Timelines, Storage, Network, etc.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as answered. I assume it did?